# Выделение первой статьи отдельным дивом

Tags: php

Статьи выводятся в цикле обычным способом

```
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`="1" AND `iconka`="1" AND `pobeda`="0"'), 0);
if($count>0) 
{ 
$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`='1' AND `iconka`='1' AND `pobeda`='0' ORDER BY `golosov` DESC, `time` ASC, `comments` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
```

Нужно сделать выделение первой статьи отдельным дивом. Что-то не соображу, как это сделать.

---

См. картинку:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Универсальный вариант может выглядеть так:

```
$first = true;
while ($row = ...
{
    if ($first) {
        // О чудо! Я первый
        $first = false;
    }
}
```

Если же вы сохраняете свои статьи в одну какую-то переменную, то еще и так можно:

```
$content = '';
while ($row = ...
{
    if (empty($content)) {
        // Я тоже первый!
    }
}
```

p.s: сомнительное удовольствие делать `COUNT` перед выборкой. Разве, если у вас там дальше листалка реализуется. Если ваш второй `SELECT` ничего не вернет, то цикл просто не выполнится.

*p.p.s.: обычным способом - забавное определение :)*

Comment: Ну, так довели ответ до конца...

    $req = mysql_query(" ... запрос ... ");
    if(mysql_num_rows($req) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) {
            // ... 
        }
    }

Comment: Листалка дальше есть

}
if ($count > $message) { 
echo '<div class="navigations">'.pagenav('top.php?', $start, $count, $message).'</div>'; 
} 
}
else {
echo '<h5>Статьи еще не добавлены!</h5>'; 
}

Comment: @Deonis, вопрос был не о запросе, потому не хочу всё смешивать. К тому же, у человека, в теории, листалка есть, а значит ``COUNT`` всё равно нужен. 
Вывод же можно сократить и до такого вида:

    $req = mysql_query("SELECT ... ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       // Не выполнится, если ответ пустой
    }

Какая-то у меня некрасивая подсветка..

Comment: Что-то фигня получается.

echo '<div class="cont_cent-the_best-wrapper">'; - спец.див для выделения

Comment: @vitagame, сомневаюсь, что это кому-то о чём-то говорит. Пусть будет the_best. Не понимаю, в чём суть проблемы.

Comment: <code>$req = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `moderation`='1' AND `iconka`='1' AND `pobeda`='0' ORDER BY `golosov` DESC, `time` ASC, `comments` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message); 
$content = '';
if(mysql_num_rows($req) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
$avtor = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `users` where `id`='".$row['id_user']."'"));
if (empty($content))echo '<div class="cont_cent cont_cent-first cont_cent-the_best"><div class="cont_cent-the_best-wrapper">';
if (!empty($content))echo '<div class="cont_cent">';</code>

Так все статьи выделяются.

Comment: Вот тю... @xEdelweiss все же вам написал (в комент все не влазит, поэтому сократил).

    $req = mysql_query(" первый запрос ");
    $first = true;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)){
        $avtor = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(" второй запрос "));
        if($first){
            echo '<div class="cont_cent cont_cent-first cont_cent-the_best"><div class="cont_cent-the_best-wrapper">';
            $first = false;
        } else {
            echo '<div class="cont_cent">';
        }
    }

P.S. В одном запросе можно вытягивать и статьи, и авторов, если что

Answer (score 0):

Псевдо класс :first-child КСС думаю тебе от поможет

Answer (score -1):

```
$first = true;
while ($row = ...
{
    if ($first) {
        // О чудо! Я первый
        $first = false;
```

Comment: Парень, да ты гениален))) Я горжусь тобой!)

Comment: ))   добавьв сскайп sasha_osipov2 плиз, мне консультант нужен!

Comment: по какому тарифу готов работать?

Comment: добавь поговорим, чё сдесь переписываться будем?

Comment: @d1b2, если тариф "один вопрос - какая-то сумма", то с вами озолотится можно, с учетом того, что вопрос в день будет под сотню )))